# Calculate sum of Column grouped by hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the total cost of staffing requirements over a day. My attempt is to `group` `People` required throughout the day and multiply the cost. I then try to `group` this cost per/hour. But my output isn't correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

d = ({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:00:00','0/1/1900 9:59:00','0/1/1900 10:00:00','0/1/1900 12:29:00','0/1/1900 12:30:00','0/1/1900 13:00:00','0/1/1900 13:02:00','0/1/1900 13:15:00','0/1/1900 13:20:00','0/1/1900 18:10:00','0/1/1900 18:15:00','0/1/1900 18:20:00','0/1/1900 18:25:00','0/1/1900 18:45:00','0/1/1900 18:50:00','0/1/1900 19:05:00','0/1/1900 19:07:00','0/1/1900 21:57:00','0/1/1900 22:00:00','0/1/1900 22:30:00','0/1/1900 22:35:00','1/1/1900 3:00:00','1/1/1900 3:05:00','1/1/1900 3:20:00','1/1/1900 3:25:00'],                 
    'People' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],                      
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Time'] = ['/'.join([str(int(x.split('/')[0])+1)] + x.split('/')[1:]) for x in df['Time']]
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T',key='Time'))['People'].max().ffill()
df = df.reset_index(level=['Time'])

df['Cost'] = df['People'] * 26

cost = df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.hour])['Cost'].sum()

#For reference. This plot displays people required throughout the day
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
plt.plot(df['Time'], df['People'], color = 'blue')

plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.ylabel('People Required', labelpad = 10)
plt.xlabel('Time', labelpad = 10)

print(cost)
```

Out:

```
0     416.0
1     416.0
2     416.0
3     130.0
8     104.0
9     104.0
10    208.0
11    208.0
12    260.0
13    312.0
14    312.0
15    312.0
16    312.0
17    312.0
18    364.0
19    312.0
20    312.0
21    312.0
22    416.0
23    416.0
```

I have done the calculations manually an the total cost output should be:

```
$1456
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be `0/1/1900 8:00:00`? xD

Comment: My timestamps go past midnight so I have to manually add a date so timestamps past midnight come last instead of first. It's been a real pain

Comment: That's fine but do use a valid date! :D

Comment: Yep. I'm just using what Excel provides to keep it as replicable as possible. I'll adjust when asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wrong numbers in your question is most likely caused by the incorrect datetime values that you have. Once you have fixed that, you should get the correct numbers. Here's an attempt from my end, with a little tweak to the *Time* column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1/1/1900 8:00:00','1/1/1900 9:59:00','1/1/1900 10:00:00','1/1/1900 12:29:00','1/1/1900 12:30:00','1/1/1900 13:00:00','1/1/1900 13:02:00','1/1/1900 13:15:00','1/1/1900 13:20:00','1/1/1900 18:10:00','1/1/1900 18:15:00','1/1/1900 18:20:00','1/1/1900 18:25:00','1/1/1900 18:45:00','1/1/1900 18:50:00','1/1/1900 19:05:00','1/1/1900 19:07:00','1/1/1900 21:57:00','1/1/1900 22:00:00','1/1/1900 22:30:00','1/1/1900 22:35:00','1/2/1900 3:00:00','1/2/1900 3:05:00','1/2/1900 3:20:00','1/2/1900 3:25:00'],
    'People' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],                      
     })

>>>df
                 Time  People
0    1/1/1900 8:00:00       1
1    1/1/1900 9:59:00       1
2   1/1/1900 10:00:00       2
3   1/1/1900 12:29:00       2
4   1/1/1900 12:30:00       3
5   1/1/1900 13:00:00       3
6   1/1/1900 13:02:00       2
7   1/1/1900 13:15:00       2
8   1/1/1900 13:20:00       3
9   1/1/1900 18:10:00       3
10  1/1/1900 18:15:00       4
11  1/1/1900 18:20:00       4
12  1/1/1900 18:25:00       3
13  1/1/1900 18:45:00       3
14  1/1/1900 18:50:00       2
15  1/1/1900 19:05:00       2
16  1/1/1900 19:07:00       3
17  1/1/1900 21:57:00       3
18  1/1/1900 22:00:00       4
19  1/1/1900 22:30:00       4
20  1/1/1900 22:35:00       3
21   1/2/1900 3:00:00       3
22   1/2/1900 3:05:00       2
23   1/2/1900 3:20:00       2
24   1/2/1900 3:25:00       1

df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df.Time.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df_group = df.resample('15T').max().ffill()
df_hour = df_group.resample('1h').max()
df_hour['Cost'] = df_hour['People'] * 26

>>>df_hour
                     People   Cost
Time
1900-01-01 08:00:00     1.0   26.0
1900-01-01 09:00:00     1.0   26.0
1900-01-01 10:00:00     2.0   52.0
1900-01-01 11:00:00     2.0   52.0
1900-01-01 12:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 13:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 14:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 15:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 16:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 17:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 18:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-01 19:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 20:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 21:00:00     3.0   78.0
1900-01-01 22:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-01 23:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-02 00:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-02 01:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-02 02:00:00     4.0  104.0
1900-01-02 03:00:00     3.0   78.0

>>>df_hour.sum()
People      60.0
Cost      1560.0
dtype: float64
```

**Edit:** Took me reading the second time to realize the methodology that you're using. The incorrect number that you got is likely due to grouping by `sum()` after you performed a `ffill()` on your aggregated *People* column. Since `ffill()` fills the holes from the last valid value, you actually overestimated your cost for these periods. You should be using `max()` again, to find the maximum number of headcount required for that hour.